# library placed in wrong location, not found

Tags: python, py2app

I get an error message when running app created by py2app.  Apparently, a library is placed where it can't be found.  If its's placed so it can be found, the app segfaults.

Here's an mwe:

mwe:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
import json
from datetime import date
import sys

class FileDialogDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FileDialogDemo, self).__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.btn = QPushButton("Velg Excel-fil")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.loadFileDialog)

        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Last opp Excel-dokument")

    def loadFileDialog(self):
        filepath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Åpne Excel-fil", "", "Excel Files (*.xls *.xlsx)")
        if filepath:
            print(f"Du valgte filen: {filepath}")
            with open("config.json", "w") as f:
                json.dump({"filepath": filepath}, f)
            self.close()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = FileDialogDemo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

$python3.9 setup.py py2app

$./dist/mwe.app/Contents/MacOS/mwe
```

raises

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/roffe/Documents/prosjekter/mwe.py/dist/mwe.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 161, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/roffe/Documents/prosjekter/mwe.py/dist/mwe.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 84, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/roffe/Documents/prosjekter/mwe.py/dist/mwe.app/Contents/Resources/mwe.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/roffe/Documents/prosjekter/mwe.py/dist/mwe.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/PySide6/QtWidgets.abi3.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libshiboken6.abi3.6.5.dylib
  Referenced from: <2A2824C7-0077-3109-9944-32020F57621C> /Users/roffe/Documents/prosjekter/mwe.py/dist/mwe.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/PySide6/QtWidgets.abi3.so
  Reason: tried: '/Users/roffe/Documents/prosjekter/mwe.py/dist/mwe.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/PySide6/libshiboken6.abi3.6.5.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/roffe/Documents/prosjekter/mwe.py/dist/mwe.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/PySide6/Qt/lib/libshiboken6.abi3.6.5.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/roffe/Documents/prosjekter/mwe.py/dist/mwe.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/PySide6/libshiboken6.abi3.6.5.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/roffe/Documents/prosjekter/mwe.py/dist/mwe.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/PySide6/Qt/lib/libshiboken6.abi3.6.5.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/roffe/Documents/prosjekter/mwe.py/dist/mwe.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/../../../../../../../lib/libshiboken6.abi3.6.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libshiboken6.abi3.6.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libshiboken6.abi3.6.5.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
2023-09-02 19:26:41.284 mwe[99161:948342] Launch error
2023-09-02 19:26:41.285 mwe[99161:948342] Launch error
See the py2app website for debugging launch issues
```

setup.py is

"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

```
Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = [ 'mwe.py' ]
DATA_FILES = [  ]

OPTIONS = {
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Moving library to a place where it is found raises an exception and the process terminates.

Setup is python 3.9, MacBook Pro running m1. Same issue with python 3.10 and 3.11.